# Spring RestTemplete - Could not map XML to Object

Tags: xml, spring, jaxb, resttemplate, yahoo-weather-api

I'm new to Spring and I'm using RestTemplete to map the response from Yahoo Weather API to POJO objects. All I want is the "yweather:forecast" under "item", but for some reason it could not be mapped to the class I created, so does "yweather:condition", but I tried map "title" and it worked, so I'm confused about where I did wrong. Here is the XML response:

```
<rss xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Yahoo! Weather - Dallas, TX</title>
    <link>...</link>
    <description>Yahoo! Weather for Dallas, TX</description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <lastBuildDate>Sun, 14 Dec 2014 8:52 am CST</lastBuildDate>
    <ttl>60</ttl>
    <yweather:location city="Dallas" region="TX" country="US"/>
    <yweather:units temperature="F" distance="mi" pressure="in" speed="mph"/>
    <yweather:wind chill="62" direction="160" speed="14"/>
    <yweather:atmosphere humidity="90" visibility="4" pressure="29.99" rising="1"/>
    <yweather:astronomy sunrise="7:20 am" sunset="5:21 pm"/>
    <image>...</image>
    <item>
        <title>Conditions for Dallas, TX at 8:52 am CST</title>
        <geo:lat>32.85</geo:lat>
        <geo:long>-96.85</geo:long>
        <link>...</link>
        <pubDate>Sun, 14 Dec 2014 8:52 am CST</pubDate>
        <yweather:condition text="Cloudy" code="26" temp="62" date="Sun, 14 Dec 2014 8:52 am CST"/>
        <description>...</description>
        <yweather:forecast day="Sun" date="14 Dec 2014" low="53" high="69" text="PM Thunderstorms" code="38"/>
        <yweather:forecast day="Mon" date="15 Dec 2014" low="42" high="66" text="Sunny" code="32"/>
        <yweather:forecast day="Tue" date="16 Dec 2014" low="41" high="57" text="Sunny" code="32"/>
        <yweather:forecast day="Wed" date="17 Dec 2014" low="46" high="51" text="PM Light Rain" code="11"/>
        <yweather:forecast day="Thu" date="18 Dec 2014" low="47" high="54" text="Light Rain" code="11"/>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">USTX0327_2014_12_18_7_00_CST</guid>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Rss class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "rss")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Rss {

    @XmlElement(name = "channel")
    private Channel channel;

}
```

Channel class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Channel {

    @XmlElement(name="item")
    private Item item;

}
```

Item class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    @XmlElement(name="yweather:forecast", type = Forecast.class)
    private List<Forecast> forecast;

    //Don't really need, just for testing
    @XmlElement(name = "yweather:condition", type = Condition.class)
    private Condition condition;

    //Don't really need, just for testing
    @XmlElement(name = "title")
    private String title;

}
```

Forecast class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Forecast {

    @XmlAttribute(name="day")
    private String day;
    @XmlAttribute(name="date")
    private String date;
    @XmlAttribute(name="low")
    private int low;
    @XmlAttribute(name="high")
    private int high;
    @XmlAttribute(name="text")
    private String text;
    @XmlAttribute(name="code")
    private int code;

}
```

The driver:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Rss rss = restTemplate.getForObject("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=75248", Rss.class);
        System.out.println(rss);
    }
}
```

And here is the object tree during debuging:

[image]

The title got mapped, but neither did "condition" nor "forecast", I'm not sure where I did wrong.

This is the first time I use restTemplete so I just followed how people do from the internet. I'm guessing maybe it has something to do with the element "yweather:forecast"?

Thanks!

Comment: The following will help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan It worked! Thanks! Can you post an answer so I can choose?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Blaise Doughan, I found the solution in his link:

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

The problem was I did not specify the name space, which I thought is part of the element name.